# flink window for time stamp

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have stream of data like

`Eventname, Event id, Start_time ( Time Stamp)`  ..

here I want to apply window transformation on last field `Start_time` which is of time stamp, my requirement is like I want to take data for last 30 minuts.

so what I see in flink window is something this `.timeWindow(Time.minutes(30))` so I guess it take events of last 30 minutes but not respect to `start_time`

I want to take data where start_time is withing last 30 minuts, then how I write that transormation? do I need to use `filter` using that column ?

I am new to flink.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you have to do:

1. Enable event-time processing by calling `setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)` on the `StreamExecutionEnvironment`.
2. Assign timestamps to your records and watermarks. This is done by using an `AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks` or an `AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks` by calling `DataStream.assignTimestamps(yourAssigner).

In event-time mode, Flink will build the windows based on the timestamps that you assigned to your records. The watermarks tell Flink the "logical time of your data". A watermark of 1000 means that no more records with a timestamp less than 1000 are expected.

The whole topic of event-time processing is too complex to be discussed here. I'd recommend to have a look at the Apache Flink [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/event_time.html).

Comment: in this can I can give time to window by reading that column name of 'start_time' ?

Comment: the `TimestampAssigner` should read the `start_time` field and return its timestamp as a `long` value.